# if statement not executing correctly despite conditions being met

Tags: php, conditional-statements

The question says it all. Even though the conditions is being met, the code is still not running.

I tested the variables that are being compared using echo and even though they are the same(with the value of 1), the code is still not running for some running.

I have also checked my script for any syntax error and could not spot any.

Reading through stackoverflow didnt help as well as most has to do with syntax errors.

No matter what I do the output is still "condition not met", may I know whats wrong?

Below is the code:

```
<?php 

include 'database.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number=$_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next=$number+1;

    $query="SELECT* FROM questions";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total=$results->num_rows;

    $query = "SELECT* FROM `choices` WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct=1";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row=$results->fetch_assoc();
    $correct_choice=$row['id'];

    if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        echo "conditions same";
    } else{
        echo "conditions not same";
    }

    echo $correct_choice;
    echo $selected_choice;
    echo $score;

}
```

Comment: what are the real values of $correct_choice and $selected_choice? var_dump($correct_choice) and var_dump($selected_choice) ?

Comment: @Droid might be the problem. When i used var_dump($correct_choice) and var_dump($selected_choice), i get string(1) "1" string(2) "1;"

Comment: @Droid SOLVED. It is a syntax error on index page.

Comment: I did nothing ), gl there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing is print out inside if statement, then surely problem is in your form submit button name. I believe, the code for submit button should like follows to solve your problem-

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post your data" class="" />
```

And of course, form method should be POST.
Check it out, hope will work smoothly for you...

Answer (score 1):

Solved, Syntax error in index.php page.

When i used var_dump($correct_choice) and var_dump($selected_choice), i get string(1) "1" string(2) "1;".

The problem lies with the extra ;